# Apply CSS Stylesheet to only one Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, stylesheet

I have a navbar that I made using the bootstrap CSS. I would like to add it to my website which already has its CSS Stylesheet and when I attach both stylesheets, it conflicts and messes up all my styling. Is there a way I can easily add a CSS Stylesheet and have it only apply to one particular div?

For example, is there a way I could only load the CSS on that id?

Bootstrap CSS is extremely large so I'm hoping there is a way that does not require having to add #myid before each of the hundreds of CSS rules.

**Edit** It appears this is being interpreted in the wrong direction. The question is not how can I just get the navbar CSS, because that still messes up other styling.

**Is there a way I can put a #mydiv around all CSS rules in a bootstrap stylesheet (for example #mydiv { #header {CSS rule} #content {CSS rule} } so that the rule is only applied to one div or do something similar to that effect?** I know that example wouldn't work, but is there something that can be done similar to that effect to solve my problem?

Comment: _“Is there a way I can easily add a CSS Stylesheet and have it only apply to one particular div?”_ – in theory yes, with HTML5 `scoped` styles – but browser support for that is mostly lacking at the moment.

Comment: Yes by using custom nested elements like [Polymer](http://polymer-project.appspot.com/)

Comment: The question you should be asking is: 'How can I use just the navbar styles from Bootstrap'. What you're asking is not advised. You need to learn about CSS inheritance. Take a look at the individual modules in Bootstrap's source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navs.less

Comment: The reason I'm not just asking about the navbar styles is because there are styles that apply to more than just the navbar that are used and are beneficial to the navbar.

Answer (score 6):

*This is one way of doing it:*

1. You can get the appropriate css from GetBootstrap.com's customize
   page
2. Add the id="mynav" to the parent of the navbar if there is one or wrap the navigation in a div with the id="mynav"
3. Open up the bootstrap.css you downloaded, remove any unnecessary css (perhaps normalize if it's a repeat of what you have).
4. Find all navbar related styles, and put a #mynavbar (space) .navbar
5. You will then open up your own CSS and put the #mynav in front of the styles affected.
6. Since the navigation and all of Bootstrap works with border-box sizing, you'll have to change your math in YOUR css.

**HTML - Example only:**

```
    <div id="mynav"><header class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    ...
    </header></div>
```

**CSS example, there's lots of this so you have to add the #mynav before all**

```
    #mynavbar .navbar {styles}
```

---

You can get the navbar and related css and js from GetBootstrap.com's customize page:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Toggle as follows:

[image]

[image]

Scroll down and make other adjustments as you need to the colors and such to the Navbar:

[image]

Then scroll down again and click the download.

The download will contain the CSS of what you selected. Then you would open up the bootstrap.css file you got, you'll see the normalize css and other base settings and the navbar, without other styles. If there are conflicting classes, rename them and apply them to your html.

You didn't mention what conflicts but usually it's the .container class being the same or the global -- and necessary -- box-sizing:border-box that Bootstrap uses. If you see mess ups, go back into your own CSS -- not Bootstrap's, and adjust the math (include all borders and padding). Read up on box-sizing:border-box to learn more.

Comment: It's a good tip and I appreciate it, but it's still messing up my site, and there are hundreds of possible CSS rules that could be the cause.

Comment: Due to the way CSS inheritance works, you can't just load css for one div and not apply it to the other elements. You have to scope out the conflicts, rename them. Find the class names that are the same and either change Bootstrap's names or your own.

Comment: Re-read the answer, I updated it to direct you on your updated question

Comment: I think what I'm going to do is just put #mynav before all my code that uses bootstrap and hopefully I can just use the find and replace in dreamweaver and use it to replace all "#" with "#mynav #" and all "." with "#mynav ." and hopefully that will be quicker than adding #mynav manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the less css for developing your theme. [download less master from github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)

And use less compiler such as [winLess](http://winless.org/) for windows, [simpLess](http://wearekiss.com/simpless), and [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) (supports windows, mac and linux) compiling your less files.