# Apply unknown (at time of programming) stylesheet to only one div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to be able to have a system where I load a static HTML page dynamically, unknown to the developer at the time of programming, and have that stylesheet apply to just one DIV.

There are some questions that address how to do that in some specified setup like applying Bootstrap CSS to one DIV ([Applying a Stylesheet Within One Div Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493029/applying-a-stylesheet-within-one-div-only), [Apply CSS Stylesheet to only one Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577962/apply-css-stylesheet-to-only-one-div)), but not to an unknown stylesheet.

I would ideally like to be able to add CSS like the following pseudocode:

```
div.foreign-style-sheet
    {
    /* Contents of original stylesheet included at runtime. */
    }
```

but I do not find suggestions of an approach like this in the specific stylesheet mentioned in the cases above.

Given that scoped stylesheets are apparently deprecated, is there a clean way to do this?  Or is there a clean way from Python to change all selectors from `foo` to `div.foreign-style-sheet foo`? The latter is something I haven't explored in depth how to do, but is there a clean and non-deprecated frontend way to have a stylesheet only apply to a scope, or should I work on a server-side (Python) adaptation that can input CSS and prepend a given string to every selector?

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76830769/how-to-add-stylesheet-to-shadow-dom It seems to be what you'd need

Comment: A bit more background information would be helpful ... what is the big picture?

Comment: @BrettDonald The big picture is that I'd like to Ajaxify a solution as a single page application that presently uses frames and is not bookmarkable: [The Data Mine](https://cjshayward.com/datamine/), [flagship Orthodox Church Fathers site](https://orthodoxchurchfathers.com). My best thought right now is to resort to an iframe for the right pane, and work on the page as a whole maintaining a hashtag path that will let the user usefully bookmark a particular state in searching and in drilling down into individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

So let’s say that the original stylesheet contains the following:

```
h1 {color: blue;}
p {color: red;}
```

And you want to be able to import these rules into another document using Ajax and nest them inside a style rule which applies to single `div`, something like this:

```
div.foreign-style-sheet {
  h1 {color: blue;}
  p {color: red;}
}
```

CSS has [recently added support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting) for nesting like this, and current versions of all major browsers now [support it too](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20nesting). So if you are happy to ignore older browsers, you could probably make the above work.

Otherwise you could do some string processing with regular expressions to find all the selectors in the original stylesheet and prepend `div.foreign-style-sheet` to all of them.

```
div.foreign-style-sheet h1 {color: blue;}
div.foreign-style-sheet p {color: red;}
```